# Import MS Excel table into C# List with varying data types

Tags: c#, excel, list

How do I store MS Excel 2007 cell values inside C#.Net 4.0 and later retrieve them one specific cell at a time?  Note:  I do not always know the Array (table size in Excel as the rows may vary)

**MS EXCEL TABLE EXAMPLE:**

```
APPLE   |   1   |   TRUE   |   2.2
ORANGE  |   4   |   FALSE  |   3.5
GRAPE   |   5   |   TRUE   |   2.8
```

Comment: Will the Excel files be .xls or .xlsx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) is what i use on reading files from excel just download the DLL and reference it in your solution,

You can use

```
 dataRow[r] = row.GetCell(r).NumericCellValue;
```

to get the numeric value of cell

for further codes and explanation you can check [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/documentation) documentation for this

****Edit**
You even though a row contains different columns this can be done using

```
LastRowNum
```

it is a function used by NPOI to tell the end cell of a row.

Comment: I have the excel part.  how do I put the values into a list or array.  whichever is better

Comment: @fleming04 Declare list ? `List<int> list = new List<int>();`
and put this code inside a forloop
`list.Add(Cellvalue)`

Comment: but will that not save the values inside an INT vs INT, String, Double etc?

Comment: @fleming04 why not treat them all as a string then convert them into the real value if needed.

Comment: never thought of putting into string.  Thank you this should work.